# How to use delegate by sig and Permit and also writes tests for these two functions in truffle

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, ether

I'm writing an ERC20 smart contract that uses the delegateBySig and Permit functions. I'm pretty new to solidity, so i'm curious. How can I write tests for these two functions & also how do i test them on real testnet deployment. The big mystery is where to get the v-r-s parameters as required by ECDSA or what to do to get them in order to use for signing. Help a noob (:

Comment: See my implementation of [Erc20Permit](https://github.com/paulrberg/contracts/blob/7fef344585238e61d7f6e91e01cd702c4ec5b8c7/contracts/token/erc20/Erc20Permit.sol). It uses Hardhat not Truffle, though I would have recommended switching to Hardhat anyway :)

Comment: Okay thanks, also how do i get the v-r-s be used or what do i need to do first to get them.

Comment: Check out the associated [tests](https://github.com/paulrberg/contracts/blob/7fef344585238e61d7f6e91e01cd702c4ec5b8c7/test/unit/token/erc20Permit/effects/permit.ts) I wrote for Erc20Permit.

Comment: You might want to read about how [ecrecover](How does ecrecover actually work?) works.